# How do I send emoji symbols?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipod, emoji

In my app I have a chat option.

While sending emoji symbols I am able to send some symbols, but not others.

For example, if a user types <3), this works, but :D) does not.

[image]

Comment: u mean u want to send emojis ???

Comment: ya.some symbols are passing to server with code like(<3) &type where as some symbols like (:D) are not passing to server

Answer (score 2):

There are `unicodes` , those are used for displaying emojis.

So either u can display using unicodes or else there is a built in keyboard for emojis.

You just need to set that keyboard for the textfield or textview , where u need to display emoji.

Here is the link for the unicodes

http://arashnorouzi.wordpress.com/2011/08/31/adding-graphics-and-emoji-characters-to-apple-push-notifications/

Comment: You can replace the codes (":)") with their unicodes.And that will appear in your textfield or textview as an emoji.

Comment: acc to you i have to send particular code when user selected particular symbol, am i right?

Comment: but if i write like this its not sending that message to server

Comment: May be you're getting problem in connection to the server. This is not because of emojis.

Comment: but when i send love symbol or some hands symbols there are going server and i am getting while printing but some symbols not at all going to server

Comment: Then you might have done mistake in setting or replacing correct unicodes.